# how to prevent Emacs dired from splitting frame into more than two windows?

Tags: emacs, dired

In an Emacs dired buffer, if I navigate point over a filename and hit <kbd>o</kbd> for `dired-find-file-other-window`, dired successfully produces desired behavior: opening the file in a secondary window.

But if I then navigate point over a SECOND filename and again hit <kbd>o</kbd>, dired splits the frame AGAIN and opens the file in a THIRD window.

How do I direct dired to reuse the second window, such that I always have a maximum of two windows in a frame?

Comment: I don't see this behavior, either with vanilla `dired.el` or with `dired+.el`.  Do you see this happen if you start Emacs using `emacs -Q`?  If not, bisect your init file recursively to find the code that causes it to happen. Do that by commenting out 1/2, then 3/4, then 7/8,... of your init file. You can use `comment-region` to comment and (with `C-u`) uncomment the region.

Comment: How about use `a` or `RET` instead of `o` in the second window ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Raise value of `split-height-threshold` to the extend it will not do another split.

You might have to raise `split-width-threshold` also - in case Emacs thinks it's smart to split that way than.

WRT questions in comment:

The value to choose IMO depends from number of lines displayed at window. Let's assume 40 lines are displayed. If a window is split, 20 are left. Then a `split-height-threshold' of 15 should prevent further split. Preventing further side-by-side split should work respective, just consider the columns displayed.

BTW would expect a way to adapt that dynamically.

Comment: I found the offending code: `(setq split-width-threshold 0)` which I used to force Emacs to split frames by creating two side-by-side windows rather than one window on top of the other. So now my new question is, how do I force Emacs to split frames into side-by-side windows without making it spawn more than 2?

Comment: What value should I choose?

Comment: `(setq split-width-threshold 75)` seems to be working for me.

Answer (score 7):

Tried to solve the same problem using by modifying value of `split-width-threshold`, but found that it often stops working when monitor configuration changes. Ended up writing an advice for `window-splittable-p`.

```
(setq split-width-threshold (- (window-width) 10))
(setq split-height-threshold nil)

(defun count-visible-buffers (&optional frame)
  "Count how many buffers are currently being shown. Defaults to selected frame."
  (length (mapcar #'window-buffer (window-list frame))))

(defun do-not-split-more-than-two-windows (window &optional horizontal)
  (if (and horizontal (> (count-visible-buffers) 1))
      nil
    t))

(advice-add 'window-splittable-p :before-while #'do-not-split-more-than-two-windows)
```

Comment: Why `count-visible-buffers` needs `mapcar` of buffers? Isn't counting `window-list` enough? considering a window can show only one buffer at time